# Insert with AZCopy to Azure tables with original time stamp

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azcopy

I've successfully copied an Azure Storage Table from Azure to the local Emulator using AZCopy. However when looking at the local table, there is two columns that are named "Timestamp" and "TIMESTAMP". The latter contains the original timestamp, while the first is the timestamp when the row is being inserted.

I cant figure out if it's possible to keep the original timestamp with Azcopy or not? The "Timestamp" column i get is quite useless.

Comment: Do you mean keeping original timestamp in `Timestamp` column?

Comment: Yes, i mean to keep the original Timestamp column. There's no need for me to know when i copied it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you made two following steps to copy an Azure Storage Table to local Emulator by AzCopy:

1. Exporting the Azure Storage Table to local files or blobs;
2. Importing from the local files or blobs to local Emulator table.

Please correct me if my assumption is wrong.

About the column "TIMESTAMP", does your original Azure Storage Table contain this column? If not, it may be an unexpected behavior to us since AzCopy shouldn't introduce any additional columns ("TIMESTAMP" here) after exporting and importing. If this is the case, please do share us more information so that we can verify whether it's a bug in AzCopy.

Regarding your question "if it's possible to keep the original timestamp with Azcopy or not", the answer is NO. Timestamp is a property maintained by Azure Storage Table service, users are not able to customize its value.

Comment: Thanks, the answer "NO" was all i needed. It's not a problem with AzCopy at all. After looking into the tables directly, it is in fact Windows Azure (WADMetrics logs) that writes the column TIMESTAMP along with TIMESTAMP@odata.type and it became somewhat confusing.

Comment: Good to know that. :)